# Does Windows 8.1 prevent defragmentation from a SSD even in the event of running by mistake defrag on command prompt?

Tags: command-line, ssd, windows-8.1, defragment

Hope you can  me with this. I am concerned about a possible defragmentation on my SSD.

I have a laptop running Windows 8.1 preinstalled and further equipped with a SSD. Windows 8.1 has detected the SSD, which is scheduled to be optimised on a weekly basis.

To make sure that TRIM was enabled, I run `fsutil behaviour query disabledeletenotify` and the result was '0'. By accident, I also run `defrag C:` on command prompt. I immediately checked out the Defrag history on Event Viewer and noticed that "The storage optimizer successfully completed retrim on (C:) while the Recovery partition had been successfully "defragmented".

I had a look at the rest of the log entries and defragmentation on the Recovery partition happened only on that occasion (when I run defrag by mistake) as both the C: drive and the Recovery partition had been successfully retrimmed on the other occasions, so I am not sure about the extent of the damage.

I just want to make sure that my SSD has not been defragmented, so I would be grateful if you could answer these questions for me,  since I am really concerned about this:

- Is it possible that Event Viewer shows the defrag entry (because the defrag command has actually been run) but a **“real” or “traditional” defragmentation** has not really taken place since Windows 8.1 uses the TRIM command with SSDs?
- Does Windows 8.1 prevents a SSD from being **defragged through cmd** even in the event of running the defrag command by mistake?

I have done some research online but I could not find any reliable information on this and Windows Answer Tech service did not clarify anything at all.
 find below the event viewer details regarding the two entries for the same event registered at the same time: (1) the storage optimizer successfully completed "defragmentation"; and (2) the storage optimizer successfully completed "retrim" on Recovery ( see details below). I had a look at the rest of the log entries and the (potential) "defragmentation" on the Recovery partition had actually been registered only on that occasion (when I run defrag C: by mistake) as the Recovery partition had been successfully retrim on the other occasions, so I am not sure about the extent of the damage.

I just want to make sure that my SSD (or the Recovery partition) has not been defragmented.

Event Viewer – Defrag (Windows Log/Application, event ID 258) Details tab/XML view 
“The storage optimizer successfully completed defragmentation on Recovery”

```
   Provider Name: Microsoft-Windows-Defrag
   EventID 
   Qualifiers: "0" 258 
   Level: 0 
   Task: 0
   Keywords>0x80000000000000
   TimeCreated SystemTime: 2014-04-03T14:49:41.000000000Z
   EventRecordID: 1777
   Channel: Application
  Computer: VAIO
  Security:
  EventData:
  Data: defragmentation 
  Data: Recovery 
  Binary: 00000000D5010000C10100000000000022B651A2296BEDD85E9C8D030000000000000000
```

Event Viewer – Defrag (Windows Log/Application, event ID 258) Details tab/XML view
“The storage optimizer successfully completed retrim on Recovery”

```
  Provider Name "Microsoft-Windows-Defrag"
  EventID 
  Qualifiers "0" 258 EventID 
  Level 0 
  Task 0 
  Keywords: 0x80000000000000 
  TimeCreated SystemTime: 2014-04-03T14:49:41.000000000Z 
  EventRecordID: 1776 
  Channel: Application
  Computer: VAIO 
  Security: 
  System:
  EventData:
  Data: retrim 
  Data: Recovery 
  Binary: 00000000190200000B0200000000000022B63823DBB1BD381B0700000000000000000000
```

Comment: Defragging your SSD once is going to do 0 damage, you're worrying about nothing.

Comment: fragmentation on a SSD does not actually exist in the traditional sense, because the SSD is already going to write blocks where it wants to, so trying to defrag a SSD is counter productive for that reason.  SSD prevent overuse of a single cell to extend the lifespan of a single cell.  a single defrag attempt wouldn't hurt, not sure how you run a command, accidently thouhg

Comment: @Ramhound is correct.  SSDs *intentionally* fragment the data on drives in the effort to write across all cells evenly

Comment: Rather than continue your question in an answer you should use the [contact form](https://superuser.com/contact) to have your accounts merged. You'll then be able to edit this question.

Answer (score 3):

Quote from technet forum:

"Hello, In Windows 7 - we turned off defrag for SSDs as you mention in your entry; but in Windows 8, we have changed the defrag tool to do a general optimization tool that handles different kinds of storage, and in the case of SSD's it will send 'trim' hints for the entire volume;" ['Microsoft employee'](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f97425f8-3857-4aa4-9cf5-437d5e212c9c/defragging-ssds-a-default?forum=W8ITProPreRel)

However, there was a BUG in Win8 RTM: ['answers.microsoft.com'](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/performance/windows-8-automatic-maintenance-defragments-my-ssd/ac52d21c-a6c9-48de-9f22-27af6d23cf00?auth=1), so I'd have to look at the patch history to see if a fix is ever mentioned.